# Why does the momentum operator generate real eigenvalues?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, momentum

According to *No-Nonsense Quantum Mechanics*:

> [image]

How is it that $p_1 \in \mathbb{R}$ given that momentum of, e.g. a particle in space has to require a 3-dimensional vector to be fully described?  For example in classical mechanics, momentum can often be written as $\vec{p} = m\vec{v}$.

Comment: Your title and body are asking two different questions. The title asks about real vs. complex while the body asks about one-dimensional vs. three-dimensional.

Comment: @G. Smith: Corrected.

Comment: I don’t agree that you have fixed the inconsistency.

Comment: Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Comment: "We simply invented a symbol that does the work". I do not recommend this textbook.

Answer (score 4):

You can either interpret it as a single dimension, i.e. $$\hat p_x =-i\hbar \frac{\partial\phantom{x}}{\partial x},\\
[\hat x,~\hat p_x]=\hat x\hat p_x-\hat p_x\hat x=-i\hbar \hat 1,
$$or you can tack three such operators $\hat p_{x,y,z}$ together into a vector operator,$$
\hat {\mathbf p} =-i\hbar \nabla,\\
[\![\hat{\mathbf r},~\hat {\mathbf p}]\!]
=\hat {\mathbf r}\otimes\hat{\mathbf p}-\hat {\mathbf p}\otimes\hat {\mathbf r}=-i\hbar \hat {\mathbf I}$$

Answer (score 3):

The output of any Hermitian operator acting on a state has to be a real number (acting on that state). An equivalent way of stating this is that the momentum operator (or any operator corresponding to a measurable quantity) has real diagonal elements. The equation you stated above means that the eigenvalues of momentum are real. If you’re stating that above the $R^3$ should replace $R$ (since in 3D) then I can see your point. The scalar number output of the part on the right represents the value of the momentum and not a vector (in three dimensions).

Comment: This is inaccurate. Only for momentum eigenfunction is the effect of the operator multiplication with a real eigenvalue.

Comment: There is no operator multiplication with an eigenvalue. Where is that?

Comment: There is some no such thing as "the output" of an operator. Do you mean the effect of an operator? Your text is confusing as well as I accurate.

Comment: The operator acts on the eigeinstate. The Output or rhs is a number multiplied by the same state. What is inaccurate?

Comment: I agree with @my2cts that this is only true for momentum eigenstates (or in general for eigenstates of the operator that one is considering). There is no reason why the operator acting on a general state would give a number.

Comment: What about  operators for position, energy, angular momentum? Are you saying that when these operate on a state you do not get a number (multiplied by the state)? Then what do you think you get?

Comment: these guys are so wrong. Everyone knows that all hermitan operators acting on a state produce and eigenvalue multiplying that same sttate.